# Java : Need a collection type or method to extract all of data from Excel Sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I was trying to extract all of excel data: so I tried using Linkedhashmap within a LinkedHashmap (as in the code). The first Integer is analogous to row number, the second to column number and the String to cell values. When I store the values of columns and string (from inner hashmap to outer hashmap) the previous values (if any) are getting overwritten. This is observed even though I am using a new key value. Please see the sample code for clarification. Please suggest a method so that previous can be retrieved successfully or any other collection which can be used in this case.

### Code:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>> values = new  LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>>();
        LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> innerValues = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
        innerValues.put(1, "FirstSetValue1");
        innerValues.put(2, "FirstSetValue2");

        values.put(1, innerValues);
        System.out.println(values);

        innerValues.put(1, "SecondSetValue1");
        innerValues.put(2, "SecondSetValue2");

        values.put(2, innerValues);
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

### Actual Output :

```
{1={1=FirstSetValue1, 2=FirstSetValue2}}
{1={1=SecondSetValue1, 2=SecondSetValue2}, 2={1=SecondSetValue1, 2=SecondSetValue2}}
```

### Expected Output :

```
{1={1=FirstSetValue1, 2=FirstSetValue2}}
{1={1=FirstSetValue1, 2=FirstSetValue1}, 2={1=SecondSetValue1, 2=SecondSetValue2}}
```

I am fine with getting all the data from excel using poi, but I am having problem to put all the data into a collection(so that it could be retrieved successfully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Because the key is same, so it is overriding the previous values

Try this...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>> values = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>>();
    LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> innerValues = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
    innerValues.put(1, "FirstSetValue1");
    innerValues.put(2, "FirstSetValue2");

    values.put(1, innerValues);
    System.out.println(values);

    innerValues = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
    innerValues.put(1, "SecondSetValue1");
    innerValues.put(2, "SecondSetValue1");

    values.put(2, innerValues);
    System.out.println(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample code may help you

1 Importing classes

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
```

2 Class name and and main method

```
public static void main( String [] args ) {
    try {

         InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream("sample.xls"));
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

3 Itearting and displaying the results from sheet

```
Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator(); 
            while( rows.hasNext() ) {   
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                System.out.println("\n");
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                while( cells.hasNext() ) {

                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType())
                    System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"     " );
                    else
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType())
                        System.out.print( cell.getStringCellValue()+"     " );
                    else
                        if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType())
                        System.out.print( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"     " );
                        else
                            if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType())
                                System.out.print( "BLANK     " );
                                else
                            System.out.print("Unknown cell type");

                }


            }


        } catch ( IOException ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! I am not having any problem to print the data ,but to put the whole excel data into a collection. My requirement is to return the data to the main program.